# Language-specific value in grails inList constraint

Tags: grails, dns, constraints

Users of my application have the possibility of choosing some values from list. The values for that list are in simple domain class, Foo, which looks like that:

```
class Foo{

    String name

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'name', generator: 'assigned'
        version: false
    }
}
```

Foo looks the same for every language my app uses. In another class I have a constraint saying that Bar must be in list of Foo. Sometimes user doesn't know what to choose, so he may choose something like "I'm not sure" (so this option should be in list to to meet the inList constraint). Thing is, "I'm not sure" is written differently in different languages. How can I append this value based on current messages to inList constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe inList constraint will help you here - it's designed for a simpler use case than yours.

I'd add a method to the class getLanguages() that handles this, and then since you seem to be interested in validation, write a custom validator to make sure right values are saved.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you could do:

```
def theList = foo.list().name // Get any array of strings. 
                              // If you actually need > 1 field then you probably need to 
                              // put the g.message below in a map

theList << g.message(code:"im.not.sure")
```